# How to get id from url in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In my angularjs project the rooting is like this

```
{
            name: 'room-edit',
            config: {
                url: '/:view?id',
                templateUrl: function (params) {
                    var view = params.view || 'index';
                    return '/general/' + view + '.html?v=' + version;
                },
                isSecure: true,
                parent: 'generalMaster',
            }
        }
```

In the html page I am calling a function to get the information of the Room obj

```
<div data-ng-init="getRoom()">
```

And the getRoom() is like this

```
$scope.getRoom = function () {
        var roomid = 15344;
        $http.get("/rest/room/get/" + roomid + "?format=json").then(function 
        (result) {
            $scope.room = result.data;
        });

    };
```

How can i get the room id from the query string?

Answer (score 0):

Import $location like $scope in controller and

Try this

```
$location.search()['id']
```

or

```
$location.search()['roomid']
```

Comment: I tried but giving this error: $location is not defined

Comment: You need to import $location like $scope

Comment: myApp.controller('CtrlName', ['$scope', '$location',
   function($scope, $location) {
        ...
    }]);  Like this

Comment: Now it says: Unknown provider: @locationProvider

Comment: myApp.config(function($locationProvider) {
   ...
 });

Comment: The result of $location.search()['id'] comes undefined. 
The link : <a data-ui-sref="general({view:'rooms-edit',id:{{room.RoomId}}})" class="listBtn listEdit">Düzenle</a>